# Dynamic row actions for "Action" column for lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have requirement where i need to show actions in lightning:datatable but it should be different according to configuration. like i want to hide one of the action for one row but as of now we can show only actions that we have passed in "rowActions"..is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Dynamic row actions is literally in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation). What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: dynamic in a terms of row wise dynamic...!! is there any documentation on it ?like in first row i want menu of "action 1 " and " action 2" and in second row i want "action3 " and "action 4 " only is it possible ?

Comment: See the section titled "Creating Dynamic Row-Level Actions", about 60% of the way down the page.

Comment: Dynamic row actions are measured off of the row, a use case like "based on this row's status, show these menus actions". If you want a different action EVERY row maybe you should re-think your design?

Comment: @sfdcfox hey man thanx for the help...!!! i think i can work with this to implement my requirement..!!! thanx again..!!!